Reloading problem when invoking a Function Effect Angular and RXJS
When my user browses, a Guard checks the token and updates it, otherwise it disconnects the user. The update is done by calling a Rxjs Effect function in Angular. But after each execution of the secondary effect, my application redirects to the home component instead of navigating to the target chosen by the user.
#Effect Function:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { RootActions } from '../actions/actions';
import { of, map, catchError, Observable, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth/services/auth.service';
import { RootState } from '../reducers/reducer';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getAuthToken } from '../selectors/selectors';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { StorageManagementService } from '../../auth/services/storage-management.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenEffects {
  token: string = '';
  observable: Observable<string> = new Observable();
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private store: Store<RootState>,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.store.select(getAuthToken).subscribe(token => (this.token = token));
  }

  loadToken$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(RootActions.loadToken),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.authService.renewToken(this.token).pipe(
          map(response =>
            RootActions.setAuthTokenValue({ authToken: response.authToken })
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(RootActions.loadTokenFailure({ error: 'errer' }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
}

#AuthGuard :

canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.authService.jwtToken$.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated.isAuthenticated) {
          return this.authService.getIfIsInAProdEnv().pipe(
            map(isUseSAML => {
              const isProdEnv = isUseSAML;
              return this.redirectToLoginPage(isProdEnv);
            })
          );
        } else if (isAuthenticated.token) {
          return this.authService.renewToken(isAuthenticated.token).pipe(
            switchMap(response => {
              if (response && response.authToken) {
                this.store.dispatch(RootActions.loadToken());
                return this.checkAccess(route);
              } else {
                this.store.dispatch(RootActions.logout());
                return of(this.redirectToLoginPage(false));
              }
            }),
            catchError(err => {
              this.store.dispatch(RootActions.logout());
              return of(this.redirectToLoginPage(false));
            })
          );
        } else {
          return this.checkAccess(route);
        }
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        this.store.dispatch(RootActions.logout());
        return of(this.redirectToLoginPage(false));
      })
    );
  }




Someone to help me ?
